# What is the meaning of 要 in these sentences?

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning, usage

While doing exercises on my book I found some sentences with a use of 要 which I've never seen before and I can't figure out the meaning. The sentences are the following:

> 他很忙，但是他应该**要**来参加我的生日晚会
>
> **要**实现梦想不是一件容易的事 and **要**把汉语学好不是一件容易的事

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three examples can be interpreted as a *future auxiliary*.

> 他很忙，但是他「應該**要**」來參加我的生日晚會
>
> He is very busy, but he「should **be**」coming to my evening birthday party.

This「要」is used in the sense of *will, going to*, like **我明天要上學** (I will be going to school tomorrow). Similarly,

> **要**實現夢想不是一件容易的事
>
> **To** realise (one's) dreams is not an easy matter
>
> **要**把漢語學好不是一件容易的事
>
> **To** learn Chinese well is not an easy matter

Comment: Thanks a lot! As @user6065 said in the other comment the first sentence can also mean "he should have attended" (past sentence)? How do I know which one is the right translation? Would I need to add 了 for the past?

Comment: @Don'tCare I don't agree with that comment's translation. `但是他應該要來參加我的生日晚會` means *but he should be coming to my evening birthday party*. To say *he should have attended*, you wouldn't use **要**; the Chinese would be just `他(昨天)應該來參加我的生日晚會` (replace 昨天 with some other past event indicator).

Comment: depends on context,
要 besides indicating future could also reinforce 应该（要 necessary, essential; necessity)
see  iciba's example sentences for 应该要, http://www.iciba.com/%E5%BA%94%E8%AF%A5%E8%A6%81
    双语例句 2)
常用词组(3),
相关词条(3),

Answer (score 2):

> 他很忙，但是他应该**要**来参加我的生日晚会

The usage of 要 denotes the **future tense** in this sentence. But I'd rather use 会 instead.

> 他很忙，但是他应该**会**来参加我的生日晚会

In my opinion, **应该会** and **一定要** are normal collocations. So, it's also correct to say 他很忙，但是他**一定要**来参加我的生日晚会， but the tone is stronger than **应该会**. 一定要 denotes a sense of "*must*" and 应该会 is "*should*" or "*would*".

> **要**实现梦想不是一件容易的事 and **要**把汉语学好不是一件容易的事

要, in these two sentences, is different from the first one. It's short for **想要**， meaning '**want**', '**wish**', '**intend**', and etc. These two sentences can be paraphrased as:

> **想要**实现梦想不是一件容易的事 and **想要**把汉语学好不是一件容易的事

or

> **想**实现梦想不是一件容易的事 and **想**把汉语学好不是一件容易的事

***The literal translation into English might be stilted***. That might be because the convention between English and Chinese is different . It could be something like:

> If you want to achieve your dream, that would not be an easy thing to do.
>
> If you want to learn Chinese language well, that would not be an easy thing to do.

More idiomatic sentences to interpret them in English could be:

> It would not be an easy thing for one to achieve his dream.
>
> It would not be an easy thing for one to learn Chinese language well.